# What is a good substitute for averaging vectors generated from Word2vec

Tags: vector, pca, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

My dataset is in the following format where for each disease I am generating a 2D vector using word2vec.(Showing 2D vectors for example but in practice, vectors are in 100D )

```
Disease                             Vectors

disease a, disease c         [[ 0.2520773 ,  0.433798],[0.38915345, 0.5541569]]

disease b                    [0.12321666, 0.64195603]

disease c, disease b         [[0.38915345, 0.5541569],[0.12321666, 0.64195603]]

disease c                    [0.38915345, 0.5541569]
```

From here I am generating a 1D array for each `disease/disease combination` by taking the average of the vectors. The issue with averaging word vectors is the fact that the combination of 2 or more diseases can have the same average vector as a totally different disease which is not at all relevant but the average vectors get matched. This makes the concept of averaging vectors flawed. To counter this, the understanding is with an increase in dimension of the vectors, this should be even less of a possibility.

So, couple of questions in all:

1. Is there a better way than averaging the output from word2vec vectors to generate a 1D array?
2. These generated vectors will be treated as features to a classifier model that I am trying to build for each disease/disease combination so, if I generate a 100D feature vector from word2vec, shall I use something like a PCA on it to reduce the dimension or shall I just consider the 100D feature vector as 100 features to my classifier.

Comment: For what kind of classifier are diseases, or diseases-in-combination, an input? (What will be the labels it predicts?) It's wrong to use the word "flawed" for "the concept of averaging vectors" - it might work better or worse for certain tasks, but you can't tell that from a naive pre-analysis based on hunches about what might happen. You have to determine it experimentally.

Comment: And if "the combination of 2 or more diseases can have the same average vector as a totally different disease which is not at all relevant" actually happened, there would probably be much, much deeper problems in your process for creating disease-vectors, like bad data, insufficient data, or bad training parameters. Effective word2vec models don't place totally-unrelated vectors at the average of two other vectors. In fact, they're really good at placing words/concepts near such midpoints that a person would agree are an equal mix of the two endpoints.

Comment: "Effective word2vec models don't place totally-unrelated vectors at the average of two other vectors" -> what I wanted to say was, once I have generated vectors for each disease as part of my training process, you can think of that process is completed.. Step 2 -> Now to generate a 1D array of size N for each disease/disease combination(size of each disease vector as specified while training word2vec)if averaging a vector consisting of 5 disease can be equal to averaging a vector of 1 disease, that is a mathematical possibility right??

Comment: In such a case, `it really now doensn't depend on the quality of trained vectors correct`? My understanding right now is although this sort of a vector collision might be a mathematical possibility in a lower dimension space, when my size of each disease vector is let's say 200, it never seems likely to be a possibility that each of the values in 200 D for averaging vector consisting of 5 disease can be equal to averaging a vector of 1 disease. What do you think?

Comment: For what kind of classifier are diseases, or diseases-in-combination, an input? (What will be the labels it predicts?)

Comment: While I've used the example of a simple average diluting/hiding out important variation, as a reason why you should try other simpler models before using averaged-word-vectors as your features, the idea that these high-dimensional vectors would exactly total up to an unrelated vector is fanciful. That's exactly what a meaningful model would prevent. So it's silly to be concerned about this "mathematical possibility" until you see examples of it happening, which I'm fairly certain you won't.

Answer (score 0):

In word2vec space, [`King - Man + Woman = Queen`](https://aclanthology.org/N13-1090.pdf) because [mutual information is indirectly learnt in the embeddings](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/allen19a/allen19a.pdf). From this observation we learn that in the context of your question, it is theoretically just to be **adding** the vectors.

So, for example, when the word2vec embeddings of two diseases are added together, the result is the embedding for a hypothetical word that represents them both. Such a word probably doesn't exist, but because of the observed linguistic regularities, the semantic meaning is retained.

When you [normalize the vectors to compare semantic meaning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/218729/376495), adding them becomes mathematically equivalent to finding the average.